# jsoncpp find member function

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I'm using **v1.6.2** of the jsoncpp library on a **Win32** platform. All's well, I'm able to parse json and access `Json:Values` successfully using `v.["firstname"]` etc.

Q: How do I find a `Json:Value` by name in a json structure?  In the documentation I've found:

```
Value const * Json::Value::find ( char const *key,char const *end ) const
```

but it doesn't specify what `'end'` is.  I've tried `""`, but it's not returning anything I can use.

Should I even be trying to find things this way?

I'm finding the documentation pretty sparse, so some jsoncpp program examples would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: According to the source code, `find` is the same thing as the index operator except for possibly not zero terminated strings (so you'd pass a `begin` and an `end` pointer). I'm not sure what you want with 'find' though. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)?

Comment: I'm trying to find a Json::Value somewhere in a json expression, based on the name of the value. Kind of random access. I thought `find` would be it. `find` is referred to by isMember eg  `isMember(key, key + strlen(key));` so it's reasonable that `end` is intended to point to the end of a string when no zero termination is present - as you suggest.  Thanks for the link - this is way in advance of what I had in mind! I can always recurse through the expression myself looking at everything, but I thought something would already be available in jsoncpp.

Comment: Since when does C have namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

To search for a key in a json structure, you can use std::find:

```
if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(),"key") != v.end())
    printf("Found it!\n");
```

v is your Json:Value objetct

Or, another solution without STL:

```
if (root.isMember("key"))
    printf("Found it!\n");
```